# 88 level on a particular digit in a numeric array?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I was working on a brute-force implementation of [this RosettaCode challenge](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Sum_multiples_of_3_and_5). I wanted to be able to handle numbers bigger than USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE so I wrote a dead simple bignum routine for adding.

If I want to limit myself to a certain number of iterations and that number is greater than 9(18) then that's tricky. So I hit upon the idea of an 88 on a particular element of the array, thus the code below.

```
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.
       03  FILLER REDEFINES DIGITS1.
           05 FILLER pic 9999999999.
           05 FILLER pic 999999999.
           05 filler pic 9.
               88 EOR value 1.
           05 filler pic 9999999999.
           05 filler pic 9999999999.
```

So I'm still wondering if this is the only way to go or is there some other way of handling when I get to 10^20.

This is the full "solution". It's a mess but it almost working.

```
   identification division.
   program-id. Program1.

   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01  COUNTER.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.
       03  FILLER REDEFINES DIGITS1.
           05 filler pic 9999999999.
           05 FILLER pic 9999999999.
           05 filler pic 9999999999.
           05 filler pic 999.
           05 filler pic 9.
               88 EOR value 1.
           05 filler pic 999999.

   01  INCREMENTOR.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.

   01  ACCUMULATOR.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.

   01  IN-NUMBER   usage binary-double unsigned.
   01  I               USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE UNSIGNED.
   01  N               USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE UNSIGNED.
   01  THREE-COUNTER   USAGE BINARY-CHAR value 1.
       88 IS-THREE VALUE 3.
   01  FIVE-COUNTER    USAGE BINARY-CHAR value 1.
       88 IS-FIVE VALUE 5.
   01  ANSWER pic x(40).       
   procedure division.
       initialize COUNTER ACCUMULATOR incrementor.
   10-MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       move 1 to IN-NUMBER.
       call "MOVENUMTOBIGNUM" using by content in-number 
           by reference incrementor.
       move 1 to IN-NUMBER.
       call "MOVENUMTOBIGNUM" using by content in-number 
           by reference counter.
       PERFORM 20-INNER-LOOP WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL eor.
       move ACCUMULATOR to ANSWER.
       inspect answer REPLACING LEADING '0'
        by space.
       DISPLAY answer.
       STOP RUN.
   20-INNER-LOOP.
       IF IS-THREE OR IS-FIVE
           call "ADDBIGNUMS" using by content counter
            by reference accumulator
           IF IS-THREE
               MOVE 1 TO THREE-COUNTER
           ELSE
               ADD 1 TO THREE-COUNTER
           END-IF
           IF IS-FIVE
               MOVE 1 TO FIVE-COUNTER
           ELSE    
               ADD 1 TO FIVE-COUNTER
           END-IF
       ELSE
           ADD 1 TO FIVE-COUNTER END-ADD
           ADD 1 TO THREE-COUNTER END-ADD
       END-IF.
       call "ADDBIGNUMS" using by content INCREMENTOR 
        by reference counter.
       EXIT.
   end program Program1.

   identification division.
   PROGRAM-ID. MOVENUMTOBIGNUM.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  num-MOD   usage binary-CHAR.
   01  num-DIV   usage binary-DOUBLE unsigned.
   01  IN-COUNTER  usage binary-char.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01  num usage binary-double.
   01  BIGNUM.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NUM BIGNUM.
   10-MOVE.
       move 40 to IN-COUNTER.
       perform until num = 0
           divide num by 10 
               giving num-DIV 
               REMAINDER num-MOD
           end-divide
           move num-MOD to DIGITS1 of BIGNUM(IN-COUNTER)
           move NUM-DIV to NUM
           subtract 1 from IN-COUNTER end-subtract
       END-PERFORM.
       GOBACK.
   END PROGRAM MOVENUMTOBIGNUM.

  *Add Bignum to Bignum, modifying second Bignum in situ
   identification division.
   program-id. ADDBIGNUMS.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 IN-COUNTER usage binary-char.
   01  ADD-FLAG    pic 9.
       88 STILL-ADDING VALUE 0.
       88 DONE-ADDING VALUE 9.
   01  CARRIER usage binary-char.
   01  REGISTER-A usage binary-char.

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01  BIGNUM1.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.
   01  BIGNUM2.
       03  DIGITS1 OCCURS 40 TIMES PIC 9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BIGNUM1 BIGNUM2.
   10-ADD-WITH-CARRY.
       move zero to CARRIER.
       move 40 to IN-COUNTER.
       move zero to ADD-FLAG.
       perform until DONE-ADDING
           add DIGITS1 of BIGNUM1(IN-COUNTER)
           DIGITS1 of BIGNUM2(IN-COUNTER)
           CARRIER GIVING REGISTER-A 
           END-ADD
           move zero to CARRIER
           if REGISTER-A > 9 
               divide REGISTER-A by 10 
                   giving CARRIER 
                   remainder REGISTER-A
               end-divide
            else
               if REGISTER-A = zero
                   move 9 to ADD-FLAG
               END-IF
            end-if
            if STILL-ADDING
               move REGISTER-A to DIGITS1 of BIGNUM2(IN-COUNTER)
               subtract 1 from IN-COUNTER end-subtract
            end-if
       END-PERFORM.
       goback.
   END PROGRAM ADDBIGNUMS.
```

Comment: (blush) umm ok, will fix.

Comment: You know that GnuCOBOL can take 36 digits in a numeric?

Comment: And that for you testing of one digit to work, you have to know that there are only zeros in all digits prior to that one?

Comment: I do now. I had no idea. I started doing this thing in MFCOBOL then went to GnuCOBOL (using OpenCOBOLIDE) then back to MFCOBOL. The label "gnu-cobol" is thus a tad misleading.

Comment: Standard COBOL can indeed only have 18 digits.

Comment: 'initialize COUNTER ACCUMULATOR incrementor.' takes care of the zeros in all digits.

Comment: I didn't know at the time that the value only rises from the bottom, so you can use the 88 as a "stopper".

Comment: Did you mean to post that as a comment? For (more) compatibility with Micro Focus you could use -std=MF,

Comment: I've not got the fastest CPU, but just *counting* to a full 11 digits took four minutes. 40 digits with the rest of the code is going to take "some considerable while"

Comment: Yeah, this is worse than than "brute force"; this is "blunt trauma"

Comment: Shouldn't the code be much faster if you internally work on "native" numerics? So for emulating `PIC X(40)` you'd use 3 `PIC 9(18)` with overlapping ranges (simple `REDEFINES` to access the original data, then `MOVE` to `PIC 9(18) COMP` and calculate with those?

Answer (score 1):

Although you already don't seem to like the structure, I'll stick to it. It will work with your structure as well. No need for the REDEFINES or those other FILLERs.

```
   05  FILLER.
       10  FILLER OCCURS 40 TIMES.
            15  DIGITS1                   PIC 9.
                88  DIGITS1-MEANS-SOMETHING
                                          VALUE 1.

01  NAME-THAT-REVEALS-INFORMATION BINARY  PIC 9(4).

    IF DIGITS1-MEANS-SOMETHING
        ( NAME-THAT-REVEALS-INFORMATION )
        do some stuff
    END-IF
```

I've changed you PIC 9 to PIC X. Unless you are doing calculations, there is never a need to define a field as 9 for "numeric". If a field happens to contain numbers, or happens to have the word number, or something like that in its name, don't be tricked into defining it as a number.

Extra (generated) code ensues and it carries the meaning "numeric stuff will be done with this", so misleads. If/when you need to do a "numeric edit" for output, there's always the REDEFINES at that point. Doesn't have to have these other costs to make that happen.

I've now reverted to your PIC 9, as, after your edit, I can see you are using it for calculations :-)